# C++ about pointer used

Tags: c++, pointers

```
int main()
{
   int rows=0;
   int studId,course;
   char ch;
while(FileIn>>studId>>course)
   {
   for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
   {
       FileIn>>ch;  
   }
   rows++;
}
char** questions = new char*[rows];
```

What is the meaning of `new char*[rows]`? if rows = 10.

The file content is

```
20 1 A B C D E 
20 1 A B C D E
20 1 A B C D E
20 1 A B C D E
20 1 A B C D E
20 1 A B C D E
20 1 A B C D E
20 1 A B C D E
20 1 A B C D E
20 1 A B C D E
```

Answer (score 1):

Allocates an array of 10 elements of type "char*."

Answer (score 0):

since 'questions' is double pointer, it is made to point an array of pointers of size rows using new char*[rows] that is, after char** questions = new char*[rows];, questions can be made to point to pointers of type char. Hope I answered your question.